# Delphi: Resizing winapi window on move

Tags: delphi, winapi

The goal is to make window small (roll up) when you drag it, without making it original size, for now.

I tried to change window size in WM_MOVING call, but it just flickers like hell (changes size to small one, then in the next frame - changes size to original, repeat every 2 frames).

And if i set a flag, nothing happens, original size of the window remains.

```
  WM_MOVING:
    begin
    if(Moving) = false then
      begin
        GetWindowRect(Window, move_rect);
        SetWindowPos(Window, 0, 0, 0, move_rect.Width, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOZORDER);
        Moving := true;
      end;
    end;
```

Update 2: Full app code here, with a lot of unused variables and no error handling:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
   System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
   Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.JSON, winapi.Windows, winapi.Messages, SysUtils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  test_window : TWndClassEx;
  Window, parentHWND : HWND;
  mmsg:  msg;
  Button, Label1 :   hwnd;
  moving_flag : bool;
  move_x, move_y : integer;
  move_rect : TRect;
  window_rolled : bool;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function WindowProc(wnd: hwnd; msg: integer; wparam: wparam; lparam: lparam):lresult;stdcall;
var
  hRegX: HRGN;
  WindowRect: TRect;
  int_x, int_y : integer;
  p_rect : Prect;
begin
  case msg of
  WM_DESTROY:
    begin
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      Button := 0;
      label1 := 0;
      result := 0;
      Window := 0;
      exit;
    end;
  WM_COMMAND:
    begin
    case LoWord( wParam ) of
      1: MessageBox(Window,'Button','Title',0);
    end;
    end;
  WM_MOVING:
    begin
      if(moving_flag) = false then
      begin
        GetWindowRect(Window, move_rect);
        SetWindowPos(Window, 0, 0, 0, move_rect.Width, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOZORDER);
      moving_flag := true;
      end;
    end;
  //WM_MOUSEMOVE:
  //WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
  WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
    begin

    end;
  else
    result := DefWindowProc(wnd,msg,wparam,lparam);
  end;
end;

procedure CreateWinApiForm;
begin
  if Window = 0 then
  begin
  test_window.cbSize := sizeof(test_window);
  test_window.style := 0;
  test_window.lpfnWndProc := @windowproc;
  test_window.hInstance :=  hInstance;
  test_window.hIcon := LoadIcon(hInstance,'MAINICON');
  test_window.hCursor := LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);
  test_window.hbrBackground := COLOR_BTNFACE+1;
  test_window.lpszClassName := 'MyWindow';
  if winapi.windows.registerclassEx(test_window) = 0 then
  MessageBox(0, 'Error registering window', 'Title', MB_OK);
  Window := CreateWindowEx(0, test_window.lpszClassName, 'Random text', WS_CAPTION or WS_MINIMIZEBOX or WS_SYSMENU, 300, 300, 350, 130, 0, 0, hInstance, nil);
  GetWindowRect(Window, move_rect);
  label1:=CreateWindow('static','Label?',WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or BS_TEXT,6,25,330,40, Window,2,hInstance,nil);
  Button:=CreateWindow('button','Button',WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD,6,73,110,25, Window,1,hInstance,nil);

  ShowWindow(Window, SW_Show);

  end
  else
    MessageBox(0, 'Window already exists', 'title', MB_OK);


end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
CreateWinApiForm;
while getmessage(mmsg,0,0,0) do
  begin
    translatemessage(mmsg); 
    dispatchmessage(mmsg); 
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Window := 0;
  move_x := 0;
  move_y := 0;
  moving_flag := false;
  window_rolled := false;
end;

end.
```

Update 3: Also, I've seen somebody post an answer using SetWindowRgn, but for some reason after i call this one, window converts to "Classic" view, without shadows etc.

Comment: `if(Moving) = false then`  -> `if not Moving then` is a very basic Pascal idiom. If you want to change the form's size, use the VCL functions to do so. Probably. Why can't we have a [mcve]. Are we expected to individually take the time to build one? If you had provided one it would be far easier for us to help. Your users will hate you for doing this of course. Make the window small when moving it? That will look terrible. Better make sure your uninstall program is well tested.

Comment: You might get a better result if you use a custom `drag image` rather than try to change your window's size while moving.  See e.g. http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorCon2001/DragAndDrop/4114.htm#VCLDragImages.  Or just google "delphi custom drag image".

Comment: @MartynA the goal is to make an app in pure WinApi, without any VCL etc.

Comment: I guess it will take you a little time to make a [mcve]. When you have done so and update the question we can take a look at it.

Comment: Well, this code makes it flicker like hell.

Comment: @FreeConsulting can you please tell me how can I avoid it?

Comment: Avoid resizing window in response to "moving" notification...

Comment: @FreeConsultingd thats understandable, thats why i tried to use a basic flag, to let resizing occur only once. I also tried to use WM_MOVE call, it flickers much less that way, but flag-mode still does not work. I just dont understand why window is returning to its original size after I call SetWindowPos.

Comment: We're still waiting for a [mcve]. Have you followed that link yet? We should have a single complete source file that we can paste into an edit window and then run.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan code i posted is exactly all code I used except variables declarations. The project itself is not intended for any use, im just trying to learn some tricks in WinApi. What else do you need to understand the problem? I can refactor it to be completely copy-pastable.

Comment: If we can paste it we can run it and be sure we are running the same as you. In its current form I won't spend the time trying to make a complete program that experience tells me will be different from yours. What happens next is that I identify an issue and then you say, "ah, yes, but my code has this extra bit I didn't tell you about". It happens so often. Why are you resisting making a [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because right now the program has a VCL form with 1 button to create a form. Well, i will reform my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the issues that you will have, particularly with moving, is that several WM_MOVING message will be queued up, each containing the size of the window you are resizing, so when you resize the window you will get WM_SIZING messages queued behind a message that contains the original size. So when the resizing occurs, because the message was in a queue there will already be a WM_MOVING message behind it in the message queue with the original size.

Another, and probably more significant, problem with your code is that you do not set the result when processing WM_COMMAND or WM_MOVING message, meaning that in all probability default processing also occurs, exacerbating the problem. You should always check your warnings!

What I would try is modifying the lrect structure pointed to in lparam parameter and pass on to DefWindowProc, rather than trying to resize the window yourself.

## Edit

Here is some brief code showing you how to do it:

```
unit UnitTest;

interface

uses
  Windows;

type
  Rect = record
    left, top, right,  bottom : LONG;
  end;

type
  PRect = ^Rect;

implementation

function WindowProc(wnd: hwnd; msg: integer; wparam: wparam; lparam: lparam):lresult;stdcall;
var
  iRect : PRect;
begin
  //case msg of
  //WM_MOVING:
    begin
      iRect := pRect( lparam );
      iRect.Top := 0; // etc...
      result := DefWindowProc(wnd,msg,wparam,lparam);
    end;
//  end;
//  else
//    result := DefWindowProc(wnd,msg,wparam,lparam);
//  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: But how do you access lrect structure in delphi? I I tried to use PRect, but failed miserably...

Comment: Height and Width etc. really depend on context. I simply copied the definition from the windows documentation, just to make absolutely sure I was consistent. Often this structure has overloaded fields, but I didn't bother.

Comment: Thank you very much! I modified your answer, and it works like a charm. Seeing your answer i understand, that I was really close to an answer when tried to use PRect myself, but I really have a lot to learn.